# File operations in Python

Tags: python

I have a piece of code which extracts a string that lies between two strings.However,this script performs this operation only on a line.I want to perform this operation on a complete file and get a list of all the words lying between those two words.

Note:The two words are fixed.For ex:If my code is something like

```
'const int variablename=1'
```

then I want a list of all the words in the file lying between `'int'` and `'='`.
Here is the current script:

```
s='const int variablename = 1'

k=s[s.find('int')+4:s.find('=')]

print k
```

Comment: Exactly what is allowed between `int` and `=`?

Answer (score 3):

If the file fits comfortably into memory, you can get this with a single regex call:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(
r"""(?x)
(?<=    # Assert that the text before the current location is:
 \b     # word boundary
 int    # "int"
 \s     # whitespace
)       # End of lookbehind
[^=]*   # Match any number of characters except =
(?<!\s) # Assert that the previous character isn't whitespace.
(?=     # Assert that the following text is:
 \s*    # optional whitespace
 =      # "="
)       # end of lookahead""")
with open(filename) as fn:
    text = fn.read()
    matches = regex.findall(text)
```

If there can be only one word between `int` and `=`, then the regex is a bit more simple:

```
regex = re.compile(
r"""(?x)
(?<=    # Assert that the text before the current location is:
 \b     # word boundary
 int    # "int"
 \s     # whitespace
)       # End of lookbehind
[^=\s]*   # Match any number of characters except = or space
(?=     # Assert that the following text is:
 \s*    # optional whitespace
 =      # "="
)       # end of lookahead""")
```

Comment: `[^=]*  # Match any number of characters except =` will also match spaces. It should be `[^= ]*` (or `\s`).

Comment: Not sure if that's a good idea - who knows if spaces could also be part of the intended match?

Comment: Well, it's just inconsistent with the following `(?=)`. What you have in `[^]` should match the following loodahead `(?=)`. If the intended match could contain spaces, why bother including `\s` in the lookahead?

Comment: The idea was to not include spaces right before the `=` in the match. However, now you've got me thinking about this, this isn't working anyway since the `\s` is optional, so the regex engine doesn't have to backtrack. This could be corrected by adding `(?<!\s)` at the position before the lookahead, but since we don't know what @Shivam actually wants to allow there, I'm going to wait for his opinion on this. Alternatively, one could just do `matches = [match.strip() for match in regex.findall()]`.

Comment: @ Tim Pietzcker:spaces are not part of the match.I just want to get the words(without spaces) lying between 'int' and '='.However,I am still confused about this line in your code: text = fn.read()

Comment: Since you say "words", how are they separated if not by spaces?

Comment: @ Tim Pietzcker:Sorry!my bad!.I mean I just want to get the string between 'int' and '='

Comment: OK, then the regex can be simplified. I will edit my answer. As for `text = fn.read()` - that simply reads the entire file into the string variable `text`, so you can apply the regex to the entire text at once.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open(filename) as fn:
    for row in fn:
        # do something with the row?
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use regular expressions over whole text (you can do it over one line too). This prints strings betweet "int " and "="

```
import re

text = open('example.txt').read()
print re.findall('(?<=int\s).*?(?=\=)', text)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick and dirty ways and you're on a unix-like system.

I just should use a grep on the file.
Then i will split the string in order to recognize the pattern and the data i want.